# Creating visual effects using procedural textures/modeling

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, procedural-programming

i'm a beginner in Unity, i've learned in Graphics course about algorithms of procedural textures/modeling.
I would like to use these algorithms to create visual effects - fire, smoke, lighting, snow, etc..
Does someone knwo how to create those effects using Perlin Noise, L-System, Voronoi or any other procedural algorithm in Unity?
Better without using prepared prefabs or Particles System.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that might be interesting for you:
[VisualEffect Graph](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.visualeffectgraph.html)
[Shader Graph in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-graph.html)

On a side note however, using premade effects from the assetstore etc is not a crime. In the industry it is normal that you dont create every asset or piece of code yourself.

Comment: Thanks!
I share your opinion, but i have to work according my lecturer instructions..

Comment: I see the problem. There is a thing called Worley Noise. It is used to create a water shader/effect. Here is a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4066MndcyCk